# Delphi Query optimize

Tags: sql, database, delphi, query-optimization

In my application, I use a Query to make a selection of records. The TTable contains 100,000 records for now.

Here is the SQL of the Query (TABSQuery : Query of Absolute Database):

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4                               
FROM MyTable                       
WHERE Field1 = Field1              
Order BY Field1
```

And the button code:

```
Query1.Filtered:=false;              
Query1.DisableControls;                   
if not Query1.Prepared then              
Query1.Prepare;                
Query1.Open;                    
Query1.EnableControls
```

For 100,000 records, it takes 10 seconds. Is this execution time good?

My Table can contain tens of millions of records, so it can take tens of minutes ...
How to optimize and reduce execution time please? Or is there another method to follow?
Fields are indexed.
Thank you for your help

Comment: For this sort of question, asking to make a query faster, you really need to provide table definitions and index definitions, and it helps if you provide the real query too because if your real query is selecting 80 columns that is very different from one which only selects four (can still be de-identified if you must, but that makes it harder).

Comment: My table has 28 fields.  Query uses String fields and they are indexed

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? What is the execution plan of the query? What is the complete definition of the table? On which columns do you have an index?

Comment: In the Table, I have 28 columns                                                       
The fields of the Query are       string:                                                                     
-Field 1: String, 100                           
-Field 2: String, 100                  
-Field 3: String, 100                          
-Field 4: String, 100                                        

This Table is detail at a Table Master

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think that the execution time you say is not all that great and can probably improve.

Since you are selecting every single row in the table then the only use for indexes (in this case) is for sorting, but single-field index on `Field1` will not be used because it doesn't include the other fields in your `SELECT`.

Some options to speed the execution of *this query*

- don't sort the results unless absolutely necessary
- don't return all rows unless you are really going to use them (in my experience, there are not many situations where you need all rows and need them to be in order)
- change the index on `Field1` to also include `Field2, Field3, Field4` (the exact syntax for this depends on your RDBMS)
- if none of the above are possible see if your sort is being done in memory or spilling to disk, if it is going to disk maybe increase system RAM

And remember that changing indexes can impact other aspects of your workload so test first to make sure there are no adverse effects.